# Need help to sort out partitions with Mac OS X + Ubuntu Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mac

I have a MacbookPro8,1 with a 500GB HDD, running OS X 10.8.5 Mountain Lion.

I used the Disk Utility app on Mac OS to create a new 50GB free space partition to install Ubuntu on.

I installed rEFIt and live booted from a CD with Ubuntu 13.04 on it. While live booting I used gparted to create a SWAP area of 1GB and formatted the remaining free space as EXT4. These two were /dev/sda4 and /dev/sda5 respectively. The EXT4 was flagged as the boot loader (grub) partition.

Then, I installed Ubuntu on the EXT4 through the desktop icon while live-booting from CD with no problems. After the installing was finished, I rebooted the laptop, the CD popped out, and I got to the rEFIt boot loader screen. I selected the "partition tool" from the menu and rEFIt said it successfully synced my partitioning tables.

I shut down the computer, turned it back on, got to the rEFIt screen again and now I had two options: Boot Mac OS and Boot Ubuntu from HD. 
Whenever I try to boot into Ubuntu, I get a white screen with the Linux penguin greyed out in the middle, and after a few seconds a black screen with the text "Missing operating system..."

I suspect there is a problem with the partition tables, but I don't know how to fix it. If anyone can help I can include the report from the Partition Inspector tool that came with rEFIt.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First, rEFIt has been abandoned. I've forked the project as [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) and added significant new capabilities, particularly for handling Linux installations. You might therefore want to try using rEFInd. You should be able to use a CD-R or USB flash drive image (although these sometimes don't work on some Macs) for testing.

Second, the procedure you followed creates a [hybrid MBR,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) which is an ugly and dangerous hack that's *not* required to boot Linux on most Macs. You're usually better off [installing Linux in EFI mode](http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/) and using a conventional GPT disk. This will require using an EFI-mode boot loader for Linux (rEFInd in conjunction with a 3.3.0 or later kernel works well for this) rather than the BIOS-mode GRUB.

Third, if you installed GRUB to the Linux partition, that means that there's no BIOS-mode boot loader in the disk's MBR. If you must do a BIOS-mode boot, you probably need a BIOS-mode boot loader in the MBR, so you'll need to install one. The [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool should be able to put GRUB there, or you can do it manually from a live CD.